# Outlook Addin Event handler clean up

Tags: event-handling, outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am having problems with the event handler in my office addin . Below is an example code i got from microsoft website to explain what i mean.
I have a manifest file that uses the on-send hook as well as a click-based event triggering.
My button calls `appendMessageBodyOnClick` and onsend i call `appendMessageBodyOnSend`. Both function primarily do the same thing. I never want to block sending emails regardless.

The problem is that the event object is not properly cleaned up i think.

Scenario 1
When i click my button ; which calls `event.completed()`, and then after i try to send the message, it says my app is blocking the message, but then when i try to send again it goes through.

Scenario 2
When i leave the subject empty and then send the message, as expected i am prompted that the subject is empty. If i cancel sending the message on this note and then click on my button, the message tries to send as though i clicked send.

I am supposing the is some sort or state clean up issue. What am i doing wrong here?

Function-File.js

```
function appendMessageBodyOnClick(event) {
    // Append string to message body
    event.completed();
}

// In the following example, the checkMessage function has
// been registered as an event handler for ItemSend.
function appendMessageBodyOnSend(event) {
     // Append string to message body
    event.completed({allowEvent = true});
}
```

Comment: Which platform are you using: Outlook Desktop, old-OWA or new-OWA (option which appears on right hand corner: Try the new outlook)?

Comment: The desktop client does not support onSend so i cannot test this case on there. It works as it should...seemingly. I will have to check the new and old owa to find out

Comment: Wait, do desktop clients support onsend now? I read they dont

Comment: Based on the way the code is structured, I believe the issues you are facing are because of the fact that the APIs, you are using are asynchronous. Please refer to the answer below. Also, it helps if you can post the code related to how you are using the APIs

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but I also have faced some seemingly inconsistent behavior while understanding how to signal that event is fully completed. Once I got my edge cases fixed, then it worked.

One suggestion: Appending string to message body should be an async function. Call the event.completed() from inside the callback function. (i.e: make sure when you are calling event.completed(), nothing else is pending -like another async result)

Something like the following:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync("new body", function(asyncResult) {
    // handle success and failure
    event.completed()
});
```

Same would be for your scenario 2, make sure event.completed() is called at the very end.